# Django model field alternative name

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model which store an API response. I want to pass a dict which contain response to update a model.

```
class Currency_Trending_Info(models.Model):
    """Stores a market's last price as well as other stats based on a 24-hour sliding window."""

    crypto_currency = models.ForeignKey(Crypto_Currency, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    market = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=False)
    last_volume = models.DecimalField(max_digits=18, decimal_places=9)
    last_volume_to = models.DecimalField(max_digits=18, decimal_places=9)
    last_trade_id = models.BigIntegerField()
    ...
    ...
```

but API response format looks like:

```
{  
   ...
   'TYPE':'5',
   'MARKET':'CCCAGG',
   'FROMSYMBOL':'BTC',
   'TOSYMBOL':'USD',
   'FLAGS':'4',
   'PRICE':6276.14,
   'LASTUPDATE':1539279469,
   'LASTVOLUME':0.03845327,
   'LASTVOLUMETO':239.21394734299997,
   'LASTTRADEID':'52275450'
   ...
}
```

so my question is is a there way to define alternative name to a field or should I just change model fields to correspond API response e.g. `lastvolume = models.DecimalField(max_digits=18, decimal_places=9)` (and of course use the `key.lower()` to turn a key into a lower case string.)

any suggestions are welcome

edit:
saving to the db

```
entry=Crypto_Currency(crypto_currency="BTC", price=6276, unix_timestamp=1539279469)
entry.save()
# Dictionary with the trending data
currency_info = Currency_Trending_Info(crypto_currency=entry,**dic)
```

Comment: How are you saving each response. As in, are you not using `objects.create`?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is override model.save method to do custom task while saving object. From there you can manually assign value to each field and save it. Refer http://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-admin-cookbook/en/latest/override_save.html or [official doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/) .

It will look something like this:

```
class Crypto(models.Model):
...
   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       self.attribte_name = kwargs['value']
       super(Model, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Don't forget to call super. Because db not gonna change if you miss that.